# Label error on scope rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikz-node

Within the provided code, I want to define a TiKz scope and to scale the contents of such scope.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{result}[blue] = [draw=#1,rounded corners,align=center,label={north:\{User,Paper\}}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.5,every node/.style={transform shape}]
        \node[result] {ciao};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By the way, I got the following error:

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `north' (in 'north').
>
> See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.9        \node[result] {ciao};
> ```

Is there a way to preserve the labels within the node transformation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following solution work for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
result/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners, align=center,
                 label=above:{\{User,Paper\}}},
result/.default = blue
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.5,every node/.append style={transform shape}]
        \node[result] {ciao};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In this case you need to replace `north` with `above` (assuming, that with `north` you expect that label is above node). Since `tikzstyle` is deprecated I move node stale definition into `tikzpicture` options.

[image]

Comment: Yes, literally I just had to replace "north" with "above" in my code. Thanks for the update!